# How to change Duedate based on Payment terms in Google sheets

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, payment, invoice

I want the Duedate to change as per Payment Terms in Google sheet

```
Due date       Terms
7/20/2020      **Due on receipt**
6/29/2019      Net30
4/5/2020       Net 15
5/7/2020       Net 60
6/8/2020       Net 40
```

I managed to change the due date Net 30,15,60,40  using `=B2+right(C2,2)` in the cell and getting accurate results but i am unable to get result for Due on receipt as it does not follow the logic for the Net terms.

Comment: Please clarify the question, and post what you've tried so far. What logic should the due on receipt calculation follow?

Answer (score 0):

```
=B2+IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"\d+$"),0)
```